# Creating default object from empty value warning is generated when the tag is not present. How to resolve?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

**Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in <--php_page_file_path--> on line <-- line_number-->**

```
include('functions/simple_html_dom.php');
$content=str_get_html($submission);
$content->find('a', 0)->class='article-link';
$content->find('a', 0)->target='_blank';
$content->find('a', 0)->rel='nofollow';
$content->find('img', 0)->class='article-inner-image';
```

The variable `$submission` will get the POST data from a form. It may or may not contain `<a>` and `<img>` tags. When both are present the warning is not thrown. But when one or both tags are not present, it throws this warning. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the warning ?

Comment: You are saying that when you don't send an <a> tag, then you parse that html and then there is no <a> tag in it. Mate, are you wondering why it complains when you try to set attributes on the non existent <a> tag??

Comment: @Brice: The first two lines of the problem description is the warning thrown.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: The situation is the form is in a blog. People may insert images or hyperlink. So if they insert hyperlinks and `<img>` tag I wanna add specific class to it. I could understand the warning is because of no tags. But how can I configure to add the attributes only iff the tag is present.

Comment: This is nice but it's not the solution. It's the problem. Anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the HTML is parsed, check if certain elements exist before altering them.

```
// Check if and '<a>' tag was submitted
if($a = $content->find('a', 0)) {

  // If so, set attributes on it.
  $a->class='article-link';
  ...
}

// Check if an '<img>' tag was submitted
if($img = $content->find('img', 0)) {
  ...
}
```