# Wordpress Vs Fcgid - 500 internal server error

Tags: wordpress, apache, fcgid

I am using wordpress application with multisite concept. Also my web hosting working with mod_fcgid as a server API. At some instances the my site getting 500 internal server error. When I looked into the error log, it shows the repeated warning errors like "[warning] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/vhosts/mywjb.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/ms-load.php on line 113". How do I resolve this problem. Can any one help?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The first step in resolving it is to understand what's going on in ms-load.php around line 113

Comment: There was a similar q/a yesterday here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925487/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-warning-is-generated-when-the-tag-is-no/19925659#19925659. Otherwise, if you need help, you have to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

My Web server was working with FCGI mode. So the FCGI processing with multiple PHP requests (wordpress), and the apache logging the FCGI related errors, when the requests gets failed with FCGI.

Below is my wordpress code,

```
    111 global $wpdb, $current_site, $domain, $path, $sites, $cookie_domain;
    112  if ( defined( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE' ) && defined( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE' ) ) {
    113 $current_site->id = defined( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE' ) ? SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE : 1;
    .........
```

I have fixed this issue by shifting the server mode from FCGI to CGI.

But compared to CGI, working with FCGI only most efficient and performance boosting technology.

Thanks